# CXX ABI Error when running on a cluster

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, openmpi

I am trying to run a code on an old cluster, on which I have no root privileges. So inside my own folder on the head node, I installed a local copy of newer versions of gcc and OpenMPI, using which I'm compiling my code. As a trial, I decided to write a "hello world" program and run it on the cluster. When I compile this code as

```
mpic++ --std=c++11 -L/home/sidk/libraries/gcc/lib64 -o mpitrial mpitrial.cpp
```

where mpitrial.cpp is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank=0,size=0;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);  
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    cout<<"Hello from "<<rank<<" of "<<size<<endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Then I submit these processes through the PBS torque job scheduler to the cluster. However, each of the processes (which may be on any node in the cluster) when running, send me an error saying:

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /shared/users/sidk/mpitrial)
```

which seems to say that each of the processes is linking with older C++ libraries (because the newer libraries are in a folder /home/sidk/libraries/gcc/lib64, and not the path shown above). On the head node I've updated LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the location of the newer C++ libraries.

Can someone offer advice on how to fix this issue?

Thank you very much for your help,

Siddharth

Comment: "so I installed a local copy of newer versions of gcc" ... then "my guess is that this is because each of the processes is linking with the old C++ libraries". These two statements contradict each other. If you compiled and built with a new version of gcc, the resulting executable would, obviously, be linked with the new, not old C++ libraries. This question is confusing. You need to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi, edited it. I'm hoping it is clearer. I agree the resulting executable should be linked to the new C++ libraries. When I run it simply using mpirun on the local machine, it works, but I get the error mentioned above when I send the same code to the cluster through a job scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ldd` on the binary to verify that `libstdc++` is being loaded from this non-default path.

On the assumption that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set correctly when `ldd` gets executed, there are only two possibilities.

1) Despite `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` being set correctly, `ldd` shows that `libstdc++` is still being loaded from lib64.

The most likely reason for this is that `DT_RPATH` is set on the executable, pointing to `/lib64`, which overrides LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

As [explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath), `DT_RPATH` takes precedence over `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Update your `Makefile`, or whatever build tool you're using, to stop generating the executable with the `DT_RPATH` tag.

2) `ldd`, with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, loads `libstdc++.so` from the non-standard location without issues. In that case, any issues with running the executable otherwise is obviously an environment issue. Despite your belief otherwise, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not getting set correctly, at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The libstdc++ line from the ldd output is:

libstdc++.so.6 => /home/sidk/libraries/gcc/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b456e4e3000)

which is the correct location. I did some reading on the --inhibit-rpath option, and I'm honestly not exactly sure how to disable the DT_RPATH tag.

Since I'm using the non-default version of g++ and mpi, should I perhaps copy the new libraries to all of the remote nodes so that this path is valid on all remote nodes?

Comment: Reread my answer. If `ldd` gives correct results, you have no issues with `DT_RPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work. I found out that this error was happening because of the way the cluster has been set up- there is an ambiguity about the home folder, and each cluster has a home folder with the same name as the head node's home folder. Due to this, the compute nodes were unable to access the newer libraries (which were in the head node's home folder) and were linking to their own /lib64 instead. I put the required libraries in the common scratch space accessible to all nodes, and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to this location in the submission script, and it works now.